# Suspend computation so it can be resumed even after the PC is rebooted

Tags: kernel

Sometimes a computation takes a long time. But when I sleep in the night, I want to shutdown my PC. Next morning when I wake, I want to start *Mathematica* and resume the computation.

If you are familiar with the virtual machine `VMWare`, what I am looking for is a feature like `VMWare`'s `suspend/resume`.

Does *Mathematica* have such a feature?

Comment: Why not let the machine sleep rather than shutting it down (not entirely sure if this will always agree with running computations, though...)? You *can* save the kernel state with `DumpSave` (several Q&As on that around here).

Comment: The Windows 'hybernate' option does the job.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries have you tried that with a running calculation (I just use sleep on Windows)?

Comment: @YvesKlett I have done so in the past and it seemed to work flawlessly. Can't try it right now.

Comment: It does not have such a feature.  You either need to build resumability into your calculation manually (not always possible, but I have done this several times when it was convenient), or suspend it at the OS level as Yves and Sjoerd suggest.  (Hibernate worked for me too.)